# How to capture a remote server in different network from home?

Tags: linux, ssh, wireshark

I want to capture packets from a remote server using Wireshark. I have a Linux-based server and I can access to it through Putty. This remote server is not on my network. How could I access to a remote server packets and especially MQTT protocol from my home using Wireshark?

I used a remote SSH configuration, but it seems I can't capture the data.

[screenshot of wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU3VX.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You can run wireshark on remote server (e.g. via ssh) and transfer results back to your machine for convenience.

E.g. [this article](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4373/analyze-traffic-remotely-over-ssh-w-wireshark) has an example: `ssh root@server.com 'tshark -f "port !22" -w -' | wireshark -k -i -` - I'll run capture on remote machine, pipe results to local wireshark where you'd be able to see results in nice GUI.

Comment: You can also run `tcpdump` on remote server and write packets to file, then transfer the file to local machine and analyze in Wireshark.

Comment: I tried this command, but I couldn't capture the data? How can I debug this, please ?

Comment: It is possible to capture the loopback interface in the remote server in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @rvs answer:

```
ssh myuser@remote-server.example.com sudo tcpdump --dont-verify-checksums -i any -U -s0 -w - 'port 1883 and src 192.168.0.22' | wireshark -k -i -
```

Differences:

- make use of `sudo`
- use `tcpdump` instead of `tshark`

Please mind: you've to install `tcpdump` on your "server".

> It is possible to capture the loopback interface in the remote server in the same way?

Yes, see the parameter `-i any` ? --> any interface